# AJAX Accordion not being an Accordion

Tags: asp.net, accordion

After much work of getting my page to work with AJAX, I have an Accordion that's not acting like an Accordion.

This is at the top of the file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ajax.aspx.cs" Inherits="ajax" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxasp" %>
```

And this the whole code of the page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="asm" runat="server"/>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds1" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Enforsys_Systems_Inc_MSCRMConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT p.SUBJECTIDNAME as [Product] ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),ib.CREATEDON,109),'') as [Created_On] FROM INCIDENTBASE ib LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTBASE ab on ib.ACCOUNTID = ab.ACCOUNTID  LEFT JOIN PRODUCT p on ib.PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID LEFT JOIN SYSTEMUSER su on ib.CREATEDBY = su.SYSTEMUSERID WHERE ib.STATECODE = 0 AND ib.ACCOUNTID = '0b4181e7-aa7e-db11-851e-0012793a1184' ORDER BY ib.CREATEDON DESC">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
            <ajaxasp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" DataSourceID="sds1" runat="server" 
               HeaderCssClass="header" HeaderSelectedCssClass="HeaderSelected">
              <HeaderTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Product")%>
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ContentTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Created_On")%><br />
             </ContentTemplate>
           </ajaxasp:Accordion>
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
```

The SQL part of the whole thing works. It does pull in the correct amount of lines with the correct information, but the Accordion control is just not there. When you click the header of the line, nothing happens.

Bellow is a picture of it. If you were to click on BLUE, it should have the different dates below it.
[image]

There is no code behind.

Comment: have u consider checking this http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Accordion/Accordion.aspx

Comment: Is there really no code behind here? At least `DataBind()` should be called, as ajax control toolkit site [states](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Accordion/Accordion.aspx)

Comment: I have looked at the site, but nothing is really jumping out at me. And yeah, no code behind. I use the `DataBinder`. If that is wrong, let me know please.